# How to cancel any event in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I want to cancel an event from within that function scope.

Eg. I pressed button click event and on false validation, I want to cancel this event. Likewise i want to cancel other events also.

How can i do this in C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the scenario; in most cases: rather than *cancel* the event, just do nothing, for example:

```
private void SaveDataClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if(!ValidateData()) return;
    // [snip: code that does stuff]
}
```

or:

```
private void SaveDataClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if(ValidateData()) {
        // [snip: code that does stuff]
    }
}
```

There are some events that expose a `CancelEventArgs` (or similar), allowing to to cancel some *external* behaviour via the `args` - form-closing being the most obvious example (set `e.Cancel = true;`).

Note that in this scenario I would not have an automatic dialog-result on the button; apply that manually when (if) the handler completes successfully.

Comment: @Marc: Thx for providing usefull knowledge. I worked out for both scenario.

Comment: This only doesn't work in **cancelButton_Click** and **okButton_Click** since they have the side effect of closing the dialog.  But, yes, for any button that does not _automatically_ set the DialogResult, this is easiest.

Answer (score -3):

```
private void SaveDataClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
   args.cancel = true;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly, **EventArgs** does not have a **.Cancel** property.  Nor a **.Handeled** property.  So you will need a different kind of EventArgs, like **RoutedEventArgs**, for example.